# Unity Barracuda cannot import .onnx file correctly

Tags: python, unity-game-engine, onnx

I'm trying to implement inferencing YoloV5 models on Unity C#.

I trained my own dataset, confirmed it works on python envs.

Also, using given export.py, I converted .pt file to .onnx file and checked it works on python envs for inference.

However, .onnx files cannot imported on Unity.

Unfortunately, I tried it a month ago, I worked!! as like below.

[image]

.onnx file has its own logo, shows specifications of network.

However now, I tried every solutions that I can try, It was not loaded correctly.

[image]

New .onnx file that I exported does not have icon, also does not show specifications.

Especially, It shows error message like

```
"Assets/Resources/MLModels/best_export2.onnx">OnnxImportException:Unexpected error while parsing layer /model.24/Split_output_0 of type Split
```

What's the difference between them?

Currently, I trained yolo-v5 on window platform (tried conda and docker image), with export command like

```
python export.py --weights best_export.py --batch 1 --img-size 640 480 --include onnx
```